# Change zoom modifier key (Ctrl+MMB)

Tags: qgis-3

Is there a way to change the modifier key for the mouse wheel zoom in smaller increments?

I'd like to change it from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to <kbd>Shift</kbd> because I mostly use other software that works this way so I always hit the wrong modifier in QGIS and can't get used to it.

I looked in the Keyboard Shortcuts, but didn't find it. This menu seems to be only for keyboard shortcuts, not mouse interaction.

Comment: If this option exists, it would be in the Keyboard Shortcuts window (accessed through the Settings menu).

Comment: I looked there first but didn't find it. This menu seems to be only for keyboard shortcuts, not mouse interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a bit more digging, and as far as I can tell it's not an option to change this setting. Details below:

- "Fine-resolution mouse wheel zooming" was a [new feature in version 3.0](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#with-the-mouse-wheel). That's fairly recent. Newer features tend to have fewer customization options than old, well-established options.
- The [user manual](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog30/#feature-add-support-for-fine-resolution-mouse-wheel-zooming) describes using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key for fine resolution mouse wheel zooming. There's no mention of any possibility of changing the key.
- As you mentioned, fine zoom control is not listed in the Keyboard Shortcuts settings window. That's the logical place where you would go to change a combined keyboard/mouse button shortcut.
- It's not mentioned in Options > Map Tools, where you can set a "zoom factor" percentage.

  [image]

  - It doesn't show up in the Advanced Settings Editor when searching for "zoom."

  [image]

At this point, I feel reasonably confident in saying that there's no option to change the modifier key for fine zoom using the mouse wheel. It's probably a hard-coded key setting. In theory you could modify the source code, but unless you really know what you're doing that's not a reasonable option.

Your remaining option is to make a feature request. Before making a feature request, it's always a good idea to search for [similar feature requests](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20label%3A%22Feature%20Request%22%20fine%20zoom), in case the developers have already considered and decided against implementing the feature you want. For example, see the discussion and reasons that the feature request ["Usage of the mouse scroll wheel"](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/16586) was rejected.